# Asp.Net-Core + MongoDb - How to search database by "code" and return the original url?

Tags: mongodb, asp.net-core, url-shortener

I am unsure how to go about searching for the "Code" stored in my Database in order to return the "OriginalUrl". 
I know I can search for the ObjectId but I want to be able to search by the "Code" assigned to that ObjectId.

Currently I have a working program that takes a Url as well as a "title" and sends it to the database:
[image]

It is assigned an Objectid _id and a randomly generated 12 character "Code":
[image]

**If it helps** this is my Controller class:

```
    namespace ShortenUrls.Controllers
    {
        [Route("api/codes")]
        public class ShortUrlsController : Controller
        {
            private readonly ShortUrlRepository _repo;

            public ShortUrlsController(ShortUrlRepository repo)
            {
                _repo = repo;
            }

            [HttpGet("{id}")]
            public async Task<IActionResult> Get(string id)
            {
                var su = await _repo.GetAsync(id);

                if (su == null)
                    return NotFound();

                return Ok(su);
            }
            [HttpPost]
            public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromBody] ShortUrl su)
            {
                await _repo.CreateAsync(su);
                return Ok(su);
            }
}
```

And Repository class:

```
namespace ShortenUrls.Models.Repository
{
public class ShortUrlRepository
{
    private const string alphabet = "23456789bcdfghjkmnpqrstvwxyz-_";

    private static readonly Random rand = new Random();

    private readonly Database _db;

    public ShortUrlRepository(Database db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    private static string GenerateCode()
    {
        const int codeLength = 12;

        var chars = new char[codeLength];

        for (var i = 0; i < codeLength; i++)
        {
            chars[i] = alphabet[rand.Next(0, alphabet.Length)];
        }

        return new string(chars);
    }


    public Task<ShortUrl> GetAsync(string id)
    {
        var objId = ObjectId.Parse(id);

        return _db.Urls.Find(x => x.Id == objId).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    }

    public Task CreateAsync(ShortUrl su)
    {
        su.Code = GenerateCode();
        return _db.Urls.InsertOneAsync(su);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a filter. Doing it this way let's you create a query specifically for the "code".

```
public async Task<ShortUrl> GetAsync(string code)
{
    var filterBuilder = new FilterDefinitionBuilder<ShortUrl>();
    var filter = filterBuilder.Eq(s => s.Code, code);
    var cursor = await _db.Urls.FindAsync(filter);
    return await cursor.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
}
```

Comment: I have some experience with filters, I used one for my Delete method. I believe this is the direction I need to take but if you wouldn't mind explaining how the query works I would really appreciate it.. From what I have read my controller class will need to be set up something like this:                                            [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Get([FromQuery]FilterShortUrlDto filter)
        {

Comment: The FilterBuilder provides "blocks" to build your query. The builder itself is a generic builder, thus it is configured for the given class. In your case it is FilterDefinitionBuilder<ShortUrl>. This enables you to access the properties within these filter blocks. E.g. filterBuilder.Eq(s => s.Code, code). In the background the MongoDB driver builds the json query out of your definition. Something like this: db.ShortUrl.find({Code: "TheCode" }). This query finds everything with the given code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already know the code when calling this and that ObjectId is created on `InsertOneAsync` call. First change your repository to take `Code` as searchable input.

```
public Task<ShortUrl> GetAsync(string code)
{
    return await _db.Urls.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Code == code);
}
```

Then change your controller `Get` to this:

```
[HttpGet("{code}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(string code)
{
    var su = await _repo.GetAsync(code);

    if (su == null)
        return NotFound();

     return Ok(su);
}
```

In your controller you can access `su.OriginalUrl` if you need to only return that after getting the object.

Then in postman you can just call http://localhost:51767/api/codes?code=cmg3fjjr_gtv

Remember only `Id` works for default url parameters as setup by your default routes in `Startup.cs`.

```
app.UseMvc(routes => { /*...*/ })
```

So this wont work: **/api/codes/cmg3fjjr_gtv** unless you specifically set up routing or change `{code}` back to `{id}`. Readability of your code suffers though.

Comment: I see that this will allow me to search by " http://localhost:51767/api/codes?code=cmg3fjjr_gtv" and I understand that in order to do this I will have to change the routes in my startup.cs but I don't understand how this can get the original url.

Could you please expand on this: "In your controller you can access su.OriginalUrl if you need to only return that after getting the object."

Comment: You don't need to change your routes in startup, it should work without it. Its only if you need want to specifically call it like its an Id  `/api/codes/cmg3fjjr_gtv` and not `/api/codes?code=cmg3fjjr_gtv`. Without the routing setup you can call it like I explained above without issue. Technically code isn't an Id, so you should call it like that.


Sure, in your repository call `GetAsync()` you are returning the whole ShortUrl object. So when you call it in your controller `var su = await _repo.GetAsync(code);` you can just return the OriginalUrl like this: `return Ok(su.OriginalUrl);`